# How do I load r package on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am currently trying r programming on jupyter notebook, I am able to install `irkernel` and also install `r essentials`.

my problem is to load any of the packages I have installed.

Like I would do on `rstudio` by typing `library(forecast)` and the `forecast` package will be loaded.

I `r jupyter` it gives me error message that the package does not exist.

what can I do to load my installed r packages in jupyter notebook?

**Edit**
Even if I doubt if `r-essentials` installed the r packages I want to load, I ran

```
conda install r-forecast
```

on anaconda prompt as administrator and I saw it installed

I am working on Windows 10

**Edit**

**See the Error Message I Got**

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'forecast':
 package 'lifecycle' was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
Traceback:

1. library(forecast)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Comment: I am still waiting for help

Comment: Why not do `install.packages("forecast")` in a cell in the Jupyter notebook?